# Python Canvas повторяющаяся текстура

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Используя библиотеку tkinter, я создал canvas холст и теперь мне необходимо залить его содержимое некой повторяющейся текстурой.

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage('...')
canv = tkinter.Canvas(self.main, width=800, height=800, bg=img)
```

Подобная структура у меня работать отказалась.

Единственный выход, который я сейчас вижу это вставить БОЛЬШУЮ кучу изображений с помощью метода `create_image`, со сдвигом на размер прошлого изображения. Но это ведь не может быть правильный выход... Это ведь ужасно.
Питон 3

Как мне залить холст канвас виджета повторяющейся текстурой?

Comment: я сел и за минут 10 написал код, который просто в цикле прорисовывает изображение. Что то в стиле 

    for x in range(0, 800, img.width):
        for y in range(0, 600, img.height):
            canv.create_image(x,y, image=img)

правда заставить его рисовать у меня не получилось, но видимо я плохо знаю Tkinter.

Comment: Это было одиним из решением описанных в самом вопросе(куча изображений со сдвигом), но может есть что-то правильное?
Кстати 10 минут это как-то долго :D

Comment: погуглить, установить Tkinter.

А что Вы хотите правильного? просто библиотечную функцию, которая это сделает? я не знаю такого и не смог нагуглить.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')

canv = Canvas(bg='white')
canv.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='t.png')
width = img.width()
height = img.height()

for x in range(0, 800 + width, width):
    for y in range(0, 600 + height, height):
        canv.create_image(x, y, image=img, anchor=SW)

mainloop()
```